# Is there anything that Object.create() can do that a factory function can't do?

Tags: javascript, object

Douglas Crockford programmed the [Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) spec.

However I've read that he no longer uses it.

> ... he also stopped using Object.create (although it was only added
>   for him to the language).

[Douglas Crockford speaking about the new good parts of JavaScript in 2014](http://bdadam.com/blog/video-douglas-crockford-about-the-new-good-parts.html)

If Crockford no longer uses Object.create() is it needed?  Is there anything that it offers that can't be replicated in some way with a factory function?

Comment: Yes, create an object without Prototype by using `Object.create(null)`.

Comment: `Object.create` is so different from factory functions that I really wonder how you can compare them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object.create functionality comes down to:

```
Object.create = function(someObj){
    function noOP(){
    };
    noOP.prototype = someObj;
    return new noOP;
}
```

The intention is to create an object which you can add stuff to without modifying the upstream prototype. It is designed as a shortcut. So there is nothing Object.create can do that a factory function (or any function) can't do. Do whatever that resonates with you.

Comment: Having `new` implemented in terms of `Object.create` makes more sense than the other way round.

Comment: You mean from an ideological perspective?

Comment: From a mathematical/theoretical perspective, yes. `Object.create` is the primitive operation.

Comment: If it was up to me I'd just use plain functions,call and \__proto\__ and Object/literal. But there is the backwards compatibility rule that we can't break, so I guess this will not change. Last time when I said we are pushing new specs into js too aggressively they bashed and dragged me at reddit so I no longer say anything about these.

Comment: `__proto__` is deprecated actually (and for good reason). Sure, you could do the same thing as `Object.create` with object literals and `Object.setPrototypeOf`, but (ideologically) I don't like the ability to mutate prototype chains

Comment: In fact it's not good to mutate any Object, but you know.. All good points though.

Comment: @ibowankenobi Thanks!  The more I learn about JS the more I lose interest in prototypes, new, this, etc. etc.  Factory functions always seem to get the job done and they aren't brittle.  Maybe my code is 5% slower but that doesn't matter in a world where computers double in speed every few years.

Comment: It's ok, there more than 1 way to paint the canvas. It's your work, your style, do whatever that resonates with you.

Answer (score 2):

Then main thing `Object.create` does is facilitate prototypal inheritance. A pattern like this:

```js
function Animal(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Animal.prototype = {
  sayName: function() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

function Tiger(name) {
  Animal.call(this, name);
}

Tiger.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype, {
  scream: {
    value: function() {
      console.log('Roar!');
    }
  },
  constructor: {
    value: Tiger
  }
});

tiger = new Tiger('fido');

tiger.scream();
tiger.sayName();
console.log(Animal.prototype.isPrototypeOf(tiger.constructor.prototype));
```

is not that simple to replicate. There are polyfills for Object.create, so you can achieve the same thing without it, but in the end, what it does is pretty specific, and in some patterns can be useful.

The reason why Douglas Crockford doesn't use it, is because he doesn't use prototypal inheritance anymore (at least from that video). So you could do something like this instead of using prototype and `Object.create`:

```js
function Animal(name) {
  var self = {};
  self.name = name;
  self.sayName = function() {
    console.log(self.name);
  }
  return self;
}

function Tiger(name) {
  var self = Animal(name);
  self.scream = function() {
    console.log('Roar!');
  }
  return self
}

tiger = Tiger('fido');

tiger.scream();
tiger.sayName();
console.log(Animal.prototype.isPrototypeOf(tiger.constructor.prototype));
```

and you get more or less the same result, but it's not the exactly same. Tiger doesn't really inherit Animal in that case. It's another pattern. You can decide to use it, but it's a different approach, not something that replaces `Object.create` pattern.

With ES6 being more and more used, normally `Object.create` will be replaced, but by classes, not factory function. When classes are supported, you can do this:

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  sayName() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

class Tiger extends Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name);
  }

  scream() {
    console.log('Roar!');
  }
}

tiger = new Tiger('fido');

tiger.scream();
tiger.sayName();
console.log(Animal.prototype.isPrototypeOf(tiger.constructor.prototype));
```

Which is more or less the same thing as the first pattern. So yes Object.create does something specific, but it is still being replaced in a way with classes.